# How to un-upvote an answer that is now out of date?

Tags: support, voting, undo

We don't have the option to un-upvote or change up-vote to down-vote an answer without it having been edited.  This prevents users from being able to modify their votes to reflect technology changes.

What is the recommended approach to try to work with/around this feature?

Specific case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3323899/1497199 -- this, top-voted, accepted answer was correct for ipython as of 2010, but is now out of date.  I'd like to recind my upvote.

Comment: I am not sure that it shouldn't be expected that the answer may be out of date when it was posted almost 9 years ago. Also not sure why someone should lose reputation for correctly answering and earning the upvotes for something so long ago.

Comment: The better option is to upvote a currently correct answer or add your own answer.

Comment: Feels like retracting the gratitude you had years ago.

Comment: @brasofilo Votes should reflect how useful an answer *is now*, not how useful an answer *used to be*.  Votes are intended to be an indication of a post's usefulness, not of your gratitude for them being posted.

Comment: @Servy are you referring to new votes or older votes that may have been cast before version changes that change the usefulness of the answer in relation to newer versions.

Comment: @JoeW That statement applies to all votes.  *All* votes should [ideally] reflect how useful a post currently is.  Now that ideal is never achievable in the real world, because everyone doesn't, can't, and isn't expected to, go back and re-reflect on their votes constantly, but it's the goal we want to move closer to whenever possible.  If someone *does* feel that their vote is no longer representative of the post's usefulness upon revisiting it, we want them to change it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Simply edit the answer to mention that the solution is only applicable to versions < X of the product (or that it's no longer applicable starting in version Y of the product).  Doing that probably means it doesn't merit downvotes any more, although if you feel that just having an answer applicable to older versions isn't useful at all, the post will then have been edited, and you're free to retract your vote.